# JComboBox on a JPopupMenu

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jmenu

I'm trying to use a compound Swing component as part of a Menu.

Everything works just fine, apart from one detail: The component contains `JComboBox`es and whenever the user clicks on one of them to open its dropdown, the dropdown opens but the menu disappears. Is it possible to make the menu stay open when a `JComboBox` is clicked?

I sub-classed `JMenu`. This is the corresponding code:

```
public class FilterMenu extends JMenu {

    public FilterMenu(String name) {
        super(name);

        final JPopupMenu pm = this.getPopupMenu();
        final FilterPanel filterPanel = new FilterPanel(pm) {
            @Override
            public void updateTree() {
                super.updateTree();
                pm.pack();
            }
        };
        pm.add(filterPanel);
    }
}
```

`FilterPanel` is the custom compound component. The `pm.pack()` is called to adapt the size of the `JPopupMenu` when the `filterPanel` changes in size.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Wouldn't a submenu be more appropriate than a JComboBox?

Comment: @Max agreed with @Jesse Barnum subMenuItem +1

Answer (score 2):

are you meaning [this bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4799266)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        String[] list = {"1", "2", "3", "4",};
        JComboBox comb = new JComboBox(list);
        final JPopupMenu pop = new JPopupMenu();
        pop.add(comb);
        frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("mousePressed");
                pop.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at Jide OSS' [PopupWindow](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.jidesoft/jide-oss/2.4.8/com/jidesoft/swing/PopupWindow.java). This provides an easy-to-use solution for this problem. Works fine for me.

Javadoc is [here](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/jidesoft/jide-oss/2.9.6/jide-oss-2.9.6-javadoc.jar!/com/jidesoft/swing/PopupWindow.html).